# Django can't lookup datetime field. int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not datetime.datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm trying to group objects 'Event' by their 'due' field, and finally return a dict of day names with a list of events on that day. {'Monday': [SomeEvent, SomeOther]} - that's the idea. However while looking up event's due__day I get: `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not datetime.datetime.`
Here's manager's code:

```
# models.py
class EventManager(models.Manager):

    def get_week(self, group_object):
        if datetime.datetime.now().time() > datetime.time(16, 0, 0):
            day = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(1)
        else:
            day = datetime.date.today()

        friday = day + datetime.timedelta((4 - day.weekday()) % 7)
        events = {}

        while day != friday + datetime.timedelta(1):
            events[str(day.strftime("%A"))] = self.get_queryset().filter(group=group_object, due__day=day) 
# ^^^ That's where the error happens, from what I understood it tries to convert this datetime to int() to be displayed by template
            day += datetime.timedelta(1)

        return events
```

Here is the model:

```
# models.py
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SUBJECTS)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=EVENT_TYPES)
    due = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='events')

    objects = EventManager()
```

I created a template filter to call this method:

```
@register.filter
def get_week(group_object):
    return Event.objects.get_week(group_object=group_object)
```

And I called it in event_list.html (Using an index because it's a list view, also this is just temporary to see if the returned dict will be correct. Looping over it is to be implemented.)

```
{{ event_list.0.group|get_week }}
```

My guess is: I've broken something with this weird lookup. `.filter(due__day=day)` However I cannot find the solution.

I also tried to look for `due__lte=(day - datetime.timedelta(hours=12)), due__gte=(day + datetime.timedelta(hours=12))` something like this but that doesn't work. Any solution is pretty much fine and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so the solution for my project is to check for due__day=day(the one from the loop).day <- datetimes property to compare day agains day not day against the datetime. That worked for me, however it does not necessarily answer the question since I don't exactly what caused the error itself. Feel free to answer for the future SO help seekers or just my information :)

Comment: Note that `.day` gives just the numeric day-of-the-month.  If your search is for something on 2016-08-12, that lookup would match anything on the 12th of *any* month, which likely isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Event.objects.filter(due__gte=datetime.date(2016, 8, 29), due__lt=datetime.date(2016, 8, 30))
```

Note that it uses `date` instead of datetime to avoid too much extraneous code dealing with the times (which don't seem to matter here).